# 7 digit telephone number $d_1d_2d_3-d_4d_5d_6d_7$ are memorable if$d_1d_2d_3$ &$4d_5d_6d_7$ are same, how many possible combination

Tags: combinatorics

> Call a $7$-digit telephone number $d_1d_2d_3-d_4d_5d_6d_7$ memorable if the prefix sequence $d_1d_2d_3$ is exactly the same as either of the sequences $d_4d_5d_6$ or $d_5d_6d_7$ (possibly both). Assuming that each $d_i$ can be any of the ten decimal digits $0,1,2, \ldots, 9$, the number of different memorable telephone numbers is what?

---

In doing this problem, I thought that i should find the number of combinations of $d_1d_2d_3$ as if i was to find this then that would mean that I would be assigning the values of $d_5d_6d_7$ and or $d_4d_5d_6$

ie if $d_1d_2d_3$  was 123 then $d_4d_5d_6$ is also 123

in assigning the values for $d_1d_2d_3$ we have $10C3$ for all the values so it would be 120 but because we also have $d_5d_6d_7$ to match up with we need to multiply 10C3 with 2 to get 240

however, the answer key is 19,990 which is obviously no where close to what i got

I was wondering where I was making my mistake?

Comment: Order matters and digits can be repeated.   Also, you are free to choose $d_4$ if $d_5d_6d_7$ is the same as $d_1d_2d_3$.  Likewise, you are free to choose $d_7$ if $d_4d_5d_6$ is the same as $d_1d_2d_3$.  Taking that into account will get you close.  However, simply adding the cases counts those cases in which $d_1d_2d_3$ is the same as both $d_4d_5d_6$ and $d_5d_6d_7$ twice, so we must subtract those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for where you went wrong, As N. F. Taussig said in the comments, order matters, and digits can be repeated.

It is probably easiest to think of this problem in the following way. Choose $d_4d_5d_6d_7$ FIRST. Then there are two possibilities for $d_1d_2d_3$, but then we realize we overcount by $10$ because there are $10$ cases where the digits are all the same and $d_4d_5d_6$ is the same as $d_5d_6d_7$. There are $10^4$ ways of choosing $d_4d_5d_6d_7$, $2$ ways of choosing $d_1d_2d_3$, and ten doublecounted numbers, thus the answer is $2*10,000-10=19,990$.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way

There can be $10\cdot10\cdot10 = 1000$ numbers for $d_1d_2d_3$

Each of these can be matched either by $d_4 d_5 d_6 X \;or\; X d_5 d_6 d_7$ with $10$ ways each for $X$,

but this includes $10$ ways when *both* match, which can only happen when $d_1=d_2=d_3$

thus $1000\cdot20 -10 = 19,990$

Comment: ...out of 10.000.000 total phone numbers, which means getting such a number is very unlikely (roughly 0.2% chance).